# CentOS 7 Unable to add Gitlab package repository and install

Tags: gitlab, centos7

Objective: To install gitlab at my Centos7.
Instruction: https://about.gitlab.com/install/#centos-7
Error:

```
[root@enlabsapp067 deployer]# curl https://packages.gitlab.com/install/repositories/gitlab/gitlab-ee/script.rpm.sh | sudo bash <br>
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:05 --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed connect to packages.gitlab.com:443; Connection refused
```

Your kind assist is much appreciated.

**Debugging Check**

- CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)
- sshd - active (running)
- firewalld - active (running)
- postfix - active (running)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should not be linked to the installation script itself, but rather on some networking issue.

For instance: "[`gitlab-org/gitlab-runner` issue 4068](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/4068)" (**Unable to install Runner in CentOS**) does mention:

> Cannot replicate this, can you check local firewall and that the port is open?
>   E.g. check that the following command connects:
>
> ```
> nc -v packages.gitlab.com 443
> ```

The [GitLab Requirements](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/install/requirements.html) page does list CentOS as supported.

[`gitlab-org/gitlab-runner` issue 4555](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/4555#note_197928941) proposed, from [Mohsen Ibrahim](https://gitlab.com/mohsen47)

> I resolved the issue by following these simple steps:
>
> - Removed all files in `/etc/gitlab/ssl` folder.
> - Removed all configuration options for using a custom SSL certificate in `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` file such as `registry_nginx["ssl_certificate"]` and `registry_nginx["ssl_certificate_key"]`.
> - Used gitlab's LetsEencrypt features by adding these lines to `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` file
>
>   letsencrypt['enable'] = true
>     letsencrypt['contact_emails'] = ['mohsen@mail.com']
>
> Then reconfigured gitlab with this command `sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, really appreciate